# Regex find and replace 2 digit date with 4 digit date in emeditor

Tags: regex, replace, emeditor

I have a large CSV file that has some mm/dd/yy dates that need to be converted to mm/dd/yyyy.

eg. "02/23/19"  needs to be "02/23/2019"

My original thought was to just do a find/replace /19 with /2019.  The problem is that there are other fields that fit the search criteria such as "WELD STUD 5/8 X 6 9/16" that I don't want to be replaced.

Is there a way to do a regex search that will require a leading /##/ followed by 19 and then only replace the 19 with 2019?

Answer (score 1):

using this regex will capture the first part as one group and the year as the second one. You can then use the group to copy the data into another format.

```
((?:\d{2}\/){2})(\d{2})
```

I would usually goes something like this ( to replace by group ).

```
$120$2
```

You can test more cases on [this regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Cf2x5Y/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using EmEditor, this is how you would write in the Replace dialog box using Regular Expression with **JavaScript Replacement Expression**. This example limits the year from 2000 to 2020:

Find: 
`(?<!\d)(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d)(?!\d)`

Replace with:
`\J if( \1 >= 1 && \1 <= 12 && \2 >= 1 && \2 <= 31 && \3>= 0 && \3 <= 20){ "\1/\2/20\3";} else { "\0"; }`

[image: EmEditor Replace dialog]